# Jenkins pipeline: No such DSL method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

With this code i got an error in Jenkins pipeline. I don`t get it why?
Am I missing something?

```
node {
   stage 'test'
   def whatThe = someFunc('textToFunc')
   {def whatThe2 = someFunc2('textToFunc2')}
}


def someFunc(String text){
    echo text
    text
}
def someFunc2(String text2){
    echo text2
    text2
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **No such DSL method 'someFunc'** found among [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withCredentials, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:124)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:117)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1280)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1174)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15)
        at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:4)
        at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor878.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:40)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:360)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:226)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

remove the extra brackets from around the `sumfunc2` invocation:

```
node {
   stage 'test'
   def whatThe = someFunc('textToFunc')
   def whatThe2 = someFunc2('textToFunc2')
}

def someFunc(String text){
    echo text
    text
}
def someFunc2(String text2){
    echo text2
    text2
}
```

**Update:**

In Groovy if a method's last argument is of type Closure, then when calling the method the closure can be outside of the brackets like:

```
def foo(whatever, Closure c) {}

// Can be invoked as
foo(whatever, {
    // This is the second argument of foo of type Closure
})

// It is also the same as writing
foo(whatever) {
    // This is the second argument of foo of type Closure
}
```

The reason that the original throws is because the following code

```
def whatThe = someFunc('textToFunc')
{def whatThe2 = someFunc2('textToFunc2')}
```

is the same code as

```
def whatThe = someFunc('textToFunc') {
    def whatThe2 = someFunc2('textToFunc2')
}
```

This means that what the interpreter will be looking for is

```
someFunc(String text, Closure c)
```

and there is no such method

Comment: because with the brackets you are defining a closure that would be an argument (the last) to sumeFunc

Comment: Why does the closure make `someFunc2` cause the `NoSuchMethodError`?

Comment: Because Groovy is absolutely awful :(

Answer (score 36):

Since this answer is the first one I found when I lookup the "No such DSL method" message, I would like to add that it might also be the interface that is not matching. In my case the first parameter was a list, but I tried to call the method with an array. So please check your interface matches what you expect, and your parameters are passed in correctly.

Comment: In my case a missing second argument was causing the same error.

Comment: Basically, different argument combinations imply different overloadings of the method, this is the same as in Java. If no matching method signature is found, it will fall into "No such DSL method".

Answer (score 4):

In my case what was happening is that I was referencing a variable using: ${} that was expanding to an empty string:

`env.VAR1=${VAR2}`

in my case, var2 didn't really exists, so what I had to do was actually:

`env.VAR1=env.VAR2`.

Silly mistake from my end.

Comment: It happened for me also, thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may have also forgotten to in include your library...

i.e.

```
@Library('shared-library') _
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my checklist of the steps necessary to make shared libraries work in Jenkins:

- source: setting up a separate repository, e.g. a Github repo `helper-for-jenkins` to be reused between Jenkins pipelines,
- setup: filling the `Library` section in the `Global Pipeline Libraries` (`Manage Jenkins > System`), which includes `Retrieval methods` (such as `Modern/Legacy SCM` and `Repository HTTPS URL`),
- import: importing the shared library in your `Jenkinsfile`; if you are just using custom methods or globals from the `/vars` dir (without custom classes that would be placed into `/src`), then in modern Jenkins versions it can be as simple as:

  *Jenkinsfile*:

  ```
  library "scanner"
  ```

  (where `scanner` is the name of the `.groovy` file placed in the `/vars` dir of the `helper-for-jenkins` repo).

Note: if you have multiple `/var/*.groovy` files in the same repo, the above steps should be repeated for each of them separately (due to lack of support for lists in Jenkins settings).